# Multiple conditions on a left outer join clause in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I would like to write the following SQL query with LINQ syntax to understand the fundamentals of LINQ queries.

```
SELECT q.*, qpph.*
  FROM [Questions] AS q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [QuestionPoolPickHandles] AS qpph
    ON qpph.QuestionId = q.Id AND qpph.PickerId = 100
  WHERE qpph.Id IS NULL;
```

How can I apply left outer join and a condition in its `ON` clause at the same time using LINQ syntax? From my readings, it seems it is likely to be not possible.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```cs
var result = from q in context.Questions
             join qpph in context.PoolPickHandles
               on q.Id equals qpph.PickerId into Handles  // notice the 'qpph.PickerId = 100' is absent
             from m in Handles.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where m == null
             select q;
```

Any further elaboration will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#joining for some clues.

Comment: @KurtHamilton updated my question to show what I've done so far.

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, the example snippets are too superficial, or at least I'm not able to understand what I need. I would be glad if you can point me out.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#left-outer-join

Comment: @Train much better, thank you.

Comment: To perform a left outer join in LINQ, use the `DefaultIfEmpty `method in combination with a group join to specify a default right-side element to produce if a left-side element has no matches. so `Handles.DefaultIfEmpty(new Questions{ field1 = String.Empty, field 2= 0 })` I know field names and values are incorrect but the syntax should work.

Comment: @Train thank you for the suggestion, the syntax works. However, I'm still unable to add `qpph.PickerId = 100` condition to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s `ON` clause. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) will help you.

Comment: Why can't the qpph.PickerId == 100 be in a where clause?

Comment: @RobertRichter If it's on a where clause, the query would only get those elements. However, I would like to eliminate the joined fields on the where clause with a `qpph.Id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comments on the question, I've figured out writing the query using LINQ syntax.

```cs
from q in context.Questions
join qpph in context.PoolPickHandles
  on new { questionId = q.Id, pickerId = user.Id } 
    equals new { questionId = qpph.QuestionId, pickerId = qpph.PickerId } 
      into Handles
from m in Handles.DefaultIfEmpty()
where m == null
select q;
```